# EXCEPT ALL equivalent in MySQL

Tags: mysql

So I have a table called members and another table called group.The leader of the group is also a member

To retrieve members,who are not leaders I did the following
code:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, rank
FROM members
EXCEPT ALL
SELECT first_name, last_name, rank
FROM members INNER JOIN groups ON mid=leader;  --edited gid as mid
```

Doing this in MySQL gives me a syntax error.What should I use for EXCEPT ALL in MySQL?

Comment: Can you paste the exact syntax error?

Comment: Can you post your table structure?

Comment: Error:you have an error in SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ALL SELECT first_name,last_name,rank FROM members INNER JOIN groups' at line 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, rank
FROM members 
LEFT OUTER JOIN groups ON gid=leader
WHERE leader is null
```

Not sure if `leader` or `gid` is in the `groups` table. The column that is in the `groups` table must have a `null` check in the `where` clause.

Answer (score 1):

subquery may do, something like:

```sql
SELECT first_name, last_name, rank
FROM members
WHERE id NOT IN (
  SELECT leader
  FROM groups 
  WHERE leader = members.id
)
```

We need to know your table structure to help you further

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this scenario.

```
SELECT 
        r.col1,r.col2 
FROM    tabel1 r 
WHERE ROW ( r.col1,r.col2 ) NOT IN( 
                              SELECT 
                                  col1,col2 
                              FROM tabel2 
                              );
```