# How to copy rows from one MySQL database to another

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in different databases (WAMP server) with the same structure. I want to copy from the first database (`newkt`) to the second one (`oldkt`) all rows that do not exist in the second database (`oldkt`).

```
newkt   -> table : users (1500 records) (id, name, password)
oldkt   -> table : users (1200 records) (id, name, password)
```

I want to actually add rows to the `oldkt` database whose id doesn’t exist in `oldkt` yet.

Also if I have more than 3 columns, can these be added automatically or I do have to tag all of them?

Comment: use normal SQL but prefix table names with database name + dot like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132654/querying-multiple-databases-at-once

Comment: What you have tried upto now? if you show your sql statement than it will be easier to guide you.

Comment: Nothing up untill now I am afraid that I will mess up the tables..!!!

Comment: which DBMS are you actually using? MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Before you do ANYTHING with ANYTHING . EVER . make a back up.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do like the following:

```
    insert into database1.table  select * from database2.table where id not in(select id from database1.table);
```

Answer (score 0):

As said you should be able to perform a typical insert but by specifying the database name in the query:

```
SELECT * 
INTO TargetDatabase.dbo.TargetTable
FROM SourceDatabase.dbo.SourceTable
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response

Comment: I get an error Undeclared variable: oldkt_
which is the name of the first database

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
INSERT INTO TargetDatabase.dbo.TargetTable
SELECT * FROM SourceDatabase.dbo.SourceTable 
EXCEPT 
SELECT * FROM TargetDatabase.dbo.TargetTable
```

Comment: So I tried the following INSERT INTO oldkt_.dbo.jos_users SELECT * FROM kenaktoolsdata.dbo.jos_users EXCEPT SELECT * FROM oldkt_.dbo.jos_users
But I get the error
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.jos_users SELECT * FROM kenaktoolsdata.dbo.jos_users EXCEPT SELECT * FROM oldkt' at line 1

Comment: above code was given for SQL Server, in this case for MY SQL please use the below code with left outer join 'INSERT TargetDatabase.dbo.TargetTable SELECT a.* FROM SourceDatabase.dbo.SourceTable a LEFT JOIN TargetDatabase.dbo.TargetTable b ON a.col1=b.col1 and ..... WHERE b.col1 IS NULL or b.col2 is null ..... '

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO oldkt   
SELECT id , name ,password FROM newkt WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM oldkt )
```

[Check Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
INSERT Table2
SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE [Conditions]
```

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: Originally the OP tagged the question as both [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) and [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server). I provided answer for both, leaving it at that as it is a more general solution than a purely MySQL one. **When using MySQL, be sure to replace `..` in the query with `.`.***

[`SELECT … INTO table` does not work in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html) (although [it works in SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190750.aspx)) so `INSERT … SELECT` will help you. It works in both [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html) and [SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms189872.aspx).

You can specify table name including database name using `.` (dot) delimiter [in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html) and `..` (double dot) delimiter in SQL Server. (See also [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2132654/2157640).)

[`EXCEPT` does not work in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13019865/2157640) so instead we will use `LEFT JOIN` and `WHERE`. (See also [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16092353/2157640).)

For SQL Server:

```
INSERT INTO oldkt..users
SELECT newkt..users.*
FROM
    newkt..users
    LEFT JOIN oldkt..users USING(id)
WHERE
    oldkt..users.id IS NULL
```

When used in MySQL, just replace the `..` with `.`.

My solution works under the assumption that `id` is unique key in both tables. (Primary key is always unique.) If this is not satisfied, the join condition must be adjusted to that fact.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer but I get this error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.jos_users SELECT kenaktoolsdata..jos_users.* FROM kenaktoolsdata..jos_us' at line 1


INSERT INTO oldkt_..jos_users
SELECT kenaktoolsdata..jos_users.*
FROM
    kenaktoolsdata..jos_users
    LEFT JOIN oldkt_..jos_users USING(id)
WHERE
    oldkt_..users.id IS NULL

Comment: @KoZe You used the query I wrote for MS SQL Server in MySQL. As I wrote, replace all the `..` with `.` and it will work for you. Also see the comments below your question, especially the one asking you to specify if you use MySQL or SQL Server. I provided answer for both.

Comment: I did and had the same error ... anyway this worked insert into database1.table  select * from database2.table where id not in(select id from database1.table); might the ; did the trick ?? Its mySql

Comment: @Koze If you replaced all the `..` with `.` you could not get the same error because the original error message contains `..`. If you are running a query through `mysql` command, you always need to add `;` at the end as otherwise it does not get executed. I edited your question to reflect that you are asking a MySQL question.